# Android: Title of the action bar disappears

Tags: android

so, in my main activity, on the onCreate() method, I check if it is the app first run with shared preferences... If it is the first run of the app, the user is redirected to a welcome activity, and then, when I press the back button and return to the main activity, the title in the action doesn't show up.. I have tested with api 9 and 17, and this only happens with api 9, so I'm guessing the error must be something about using the support library for the action bar .. Can someone help me ?

Main:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // session
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // check first time app run
        session.checkFirstRun();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

SessionManager First Run check method

```
// check first run 
    public void checkFirstRun() {
        if(getFirstRunStatus() == true) {
            // set first run key as false
            editor.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", false);
            editor.commit();

            // first time running the app, redirect user to welcome activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, WelcomeActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public boolean getFirstRunStatus() {
        return pref.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the title in a couple ways:

XML:

```
   <activity 
   android:name=".....WelcomeActivity" 
   android:icon="@drawable/logo" 
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   </activity>
```

On the Fly:

```
.setTitle("TITLE");
.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

You can pass the title in an intent to if you want it to be dynamic... not sure if that is what you want:

```
.setTitle(extras.getString("title"));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: indeed, SO is just awesome ! But wait, actually this didn't work, well, it worked in the emulator, and I thought it would work fine in my real device, but I've just tested now and it isn't working.. this is strange, it should work on the device also, right ?

Comment: Yes... are you using actionbar sherlock?>

Comment: no, I'm using the v7 appcompat library, http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: I've made it! I've changed the way my applicantion runs, now when the firstRun is checked in the main activity, and if it's true, I redirect the user to the welcome activity but I finish the main activity too.. I don't really need it on the back stack because the user has to do login before enter again in the main activity. So I don't need the code you answered, because if it is the first run, the main activity will finish and then created again later, so everything will just run fine.. But again, thanks :) .

Answer (score 1):

try this in your onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu_actions, menu);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("title");
    actionBar .setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    // OR:
    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    return true;
}
```